# Photon number in optics

Tags: optics, photons, solitons

What does the term, photon number, mean in optics? I came across the term in research papers on squeezed light. One such line in a research paper reads: Quantum solitons consist of linear superposition of solitons with different photon number and momentum eigenstates.

Comment: Can you share some context? Like an example of where you saw this term used? Without context, I'd guess it's a terse way of writing "the number of photons".

Comment: @ThePhoton The term is used in a paper on quantum solitons. It is also widely used in other papers.

Comment: One such line reads: Quantum solitons consist of linear superposition of solitons with different photon number and momentum eigenstates.

Comment: Soliton propagation (in optical fiber) depends on nonlinear behavior of the fiber, so a soliton pulse with different intensity (i.e. different number of photons) will propagate differently. So I suspect this usage does in fact refer to the number of photons in the pulse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, photon number refers to the number of photons in a photonic quantum state. Fock states are quantum states with well-defined numbers of photons associated with them. They are eigenstates of the photon number operator
$$ \hat{n} |n\rangle = |n\rangle n . $$
Here, $n$ is an integer, representing the number of photons; $\hat{n}$ is the number operator and $|n\rangle$ is the Fock state.

Not all quantum states have fixed numbers of photons associated with them. An example is the coherent states. One can expand the coherent state as a linear superposition of Fock states
$$ |\alpha\rangle = \exp(-|\alpha|^2/2) \sum_n \frac{\alpha^n}{\sqrt{n!}} |n\rangle . $$
Here $\alpha$ is a complex number that parameterizes the coherent state. The average number of photons in such a coherent state is $\bar{n} = |\alpha|^2$.

If the sentence you found says that a soliton is a superposition of states with different numbers of photons, then that is similar to the situation with the coherent state. However, the sentence also refers to momentum eigenstates, which means that the spatial degrees of freedom are also incorporated. As a result, the situation is a bit more complicated, but that was not your question.

Answer (score -1):

It is generally believed that light consists of discrete particles or photons, each carrying one tiny quantum of energy. For monochromatic light the energy per photon is $E=h\nu$ where $h$ is Planck's constant. Photons also carry momentum $\vec P=h/\lambda$. At high intensity, such as is relevant to optics, the number of photons is so large that light can be considered considered a classical, continuous electromagnetic wave and only at very low intensities the effects of photons show up as intensity shot noise.

Comment: I've rewritten the question. Please take a look.